# Regular expression too big

Tags: regular-expressions, font-lock

Working to create my own major mode for sqf language (arma3 scripting) I get this error:

```
Error during redisplay: (jit-lock-function 1) signaled (invalid-regexp "Regular expression too big")
Error during redisplay: (jit-lock-function 501) signaled (invalid-regexp "Regular expression too big")
```

The issue is a list of specific built-in language commands that reaches about 2500 of them initialized as following:

```
(defvar arma-commands
  '(
    "abs"
    "accTime"
    ... 
    "worldToScreen" ;; thats the 2500th command ;-)
    ))
```

Using the common `(,(regexp-opt arma-commands 'words) . font-lock-builtin-face)` for highlighting properly raises that error I mentioned before.

Is there any right and efficient way to solve this?

Comment: You could split it into multiple font-lock rules, where each rule would handle, say, 2000 entries. Having said this, is this really a god way to highlight a language? Maybe you could find highlighting rules which doesn't require a fixed list of reserved words.

Comment: To add to my earlier response at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72596/31220 ....  Assuming 2500 words, back of napkin calculation shows that, the avg. size of each word has to be 26 = `(/ (expt 2 16) 2500)` for the jit lock to explode every time.    What is the total length of all the words in your regexp?

Comment: 2503 words as you can see it at this site: https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/Category:Arma_3:_Scripting_Commands. Actually @Lindydancer has the right answer: splitting all the scripting commands in groups although it also possible matching just a part of  it (prefix) and not the enterely word (lot of commands share the same prefix).

Answer (score 5):

[REG_ESIZE,     /* Compiled pattern bigger than 2^16 bytes.  */](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/regex-emacs.c?id=c02986e4c3c46aee6bf6ad4c0e9acd7ba9f906df#n819)

According to https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/regex-emacs.c?h=53c0690fa28f338071703f1567d2d1c4054416f0#n1231

```c
/* This is not an arbitrary limit: the arguments which represent offsets
   into the pattern are two bytes long.  So if 2^15 bytes turns out to
   be too small, many things would have to change.  */

# define MAX_BUF_SIZE (1 << 15)
```

So, I believe you are out of luck in configuring the limit.